# Datepicker code to select current and last three days date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What will be javascript code for datepicker that allow user to select current and last three days only in datepicker. I have made datepicker using bootstarp ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -3, maxDate: "0" });
  });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dT7JZ/)

[DatePicker Reference](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)